# C# what difference enum in namespace than enum inside a class

Tags: c#, class, enums, namespaces, difference

i have a question about enums that the codes are below:

```
namespace space
{
    public enum MyEnums
    {
        Enum1,Enum2,...
    }
}

namespace space
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public enum MyEnums
        {
            Enum1,Enum2,...
        }
    }
}
```

whats difference and how to use them?

Comment: 1 - scope 2 - a nested enum can be made private

Comment: the only  difference is on code maintainability

Comment: An enum is a type, just like a class or an interface. More specifically it is a value type, like a struct. The same rules apply with regard to nesting.

Answer (score 7):

Well syntactically the only difference is that you'd preface the enum type with the containing class:

```
MyClass.MyEnums.Enum1
```

versus just

```
MyEnums.Enum1
```

(in both cases the namespace is assumed to be covered with a `using` directive)

However, containing it within the class also lets you apply accessibility differently - you could have a `private` enum that is only usable within that class, while an enum within a namespace must be either `public` or `internal`.

Comment: right,

what should i prefer using about a good programming rules? first scope or second?

Comment: If an enum is only valid in the context of one class then making it a part of that class is fine (and may help with namespacing - the vast majority of enums are not inside a class.